# Inserting multiple values into a MySQL at once

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert-into

could anyone shed some light as to why this PHP / MySQL is not working? Basically I need to insert loads of rows at once from a form, so there will be multiple name fields, multiple short, med, long fields etc..  Im getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: Short1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 95
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year) VAL' at line 2
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?php


$host = "localhost";
$databasename = "pe_results";
$databaseusername = "root";
$databasepassword = "";

$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$databaseusername", "$databasepassword"); 
mysql_select_db("$databasename", $conn); 

        if (isset($_POST['Name1'])) { 
        $Name1 = $_POST['Name1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Short1'])) { 
        $Short1 = $_POST['Short1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Med1'])) { 
        $Med1 = $_POST['Med1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Long1'])) { 
        $Long1 = $_POST['Long1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['VLong1'])) { 
        $VLong1 = $_POST['VLong1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Extreme1'])) { 
        $Extreme1 = $_POST['Extreme1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['LJump1'])) { 
        $LJump1 = $_POST['LJump1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['HJump1'])) { 
        $HJump1 = $_POST['HJump1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Shotputt1'])) { 
        $Shotputt1 = $_POST['Shotputt1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Discuss1'])) { 
        $Discuss1 = $_POST['Discuss1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Javelin1'])) { 
        $Javelin1 = $_POST['Javelin1'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Date'])) { 
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Year'])) { 
        $Year = $_POST['Year'];
        }
        // Sector 2 */
            if (isset($_POST['Name2'])) { 
        $Name2 = $_POST['Name2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Short2'])) { 
        $Short2 = $_POST['Short2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Med2'])) { 
        $Med2 = $_POST['Med2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Long2'])) { 
        $Long2 = $_POST['Long2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['VLong2'])) { 
        $VLong2 = $_POST['VLong2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Extreme2'])) { 
        $Extreme2 = $_POST['Extreme2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['LJump2'])) { 
        $LJump2 = $_POST['LJump2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['HJump2'])) { 
        $HJump2 = $_POST['HJump2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Shotputt2'])) { 
        $Shotputt2 = $_POST['Shotputt2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Discuss2'])) { 
        $Discuss2 = $_POST['Discuss2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Javelin2'])) { 
        $Javelin2 = $_POST['Javelin2'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Date'])) { 
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Year'])) { 
        $Year = $_POST['Year'];
        }

        $sql="INSERT INTO results_main
  (Name, Short, Med, Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year)
VALUES
  ('$Name1', '$Short1', '$Med1', '$Long1', '$VLong1', '$Extreme1', '$LJump1', '$HJump1', '$Shotputt1', '$Discuss1', '$Javelin1', '$Date', '$Year'),
  ('$Name2', '$Short2', '$Med2', '$Long2', '$VLong2', '$Extreme2', '$LJump2', '$HJump2', '$Shotputt2', '$Discuss2', '$Javelin2', '$Date', '$Year');
";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

New error message for JW

```
Notice: Undefined variable: Short1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 95
INSERT INTO results_main (`Name`, `Short`, `Med`, `Long`, `VLong`, `Extreme`, `LJump`, `HJump`, `Shotputt`, `Discuss`, `Javelin`, `Date`, `Year`) VALUES (`1`, ``, `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `2013-04-26`, `10`), (`2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `2013-04-26`, `10`); Unknown column '1' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 3):

`LONG` is a reserved keyword and happens to be the name of your column. In order to avoid syntax error, the column name should be escape with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO results_main(Name, Short, Med, `Long`, VLong, ...) VALUES (....)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the column, change the name to a non-reserved keyword to avoid problem getting back on the future.

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, I have sorted that issue out with backticks however now I get this error:Notice: Undefined variable: Short1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 95
Unknown column '1' in 'field list'

Comment: before calling `mysql_query()`, can you post the result of this: `echo $sql`?

Comment: updated question with results, I have fixed the issue with calling $Short1, however I am still getting the Unknown Column 1 error

Comment: JW I have provided you with the information from echo $sql in the question

Comment: i have posted also the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your post array, you have something wrong with $_POST['Short1'];

Also don't use MYSQL reserved keywords, Long is a reserved keyword. If you use you should escape it by

```
`Long`
```

Comment: The Short variable is fine, i dont know why its kicking up a fuss, everything else works fine and the only thing that is different is the name. Also I have wrapped everything in backticks since posting that so no need to worry about reserved words

Answer (score 0):

I suggest by dumping your $_POST array and looking at it. According to your code variables are only set if there is a value in the $_POST array.